# Difference between variable assignments

Tags: bash, variable-assignment, quotes

I had a question that was answered here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264925/awk-fs-with-back-slashes

After that I tried adding it to a `.sh` script that starts with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

My Line:

```
category1Filenames=(\`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |
gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "(\\\\./)|(\\\\.)" } ; { print $2 }' | sort -u\`)
```

And then I print the output using:

```
for genericFilename in ${category1Filenames[@]}; do  
  printf "%s\n" $genericFilename  
done
```

But this gives me the error:

```
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
```

If I change the line to be:

```
category1Filenames=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |
gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "(\\\\./)|(\\\\.)" } ; { print $2 }' | sort -u)
```

Then it works as expected.

I'm assuming that the problem was with using the back tick characters, but I don't understand why. Probably because I don't understand the behavior of `` ` `` vs `'` vs `"`. If anyone can point me to documentation that can explain this behavior (maybe tldp) then it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The tldp bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong.

Comment: What is that call to `gawk` supposed to do? It would be much simpler to just iterate `for genericFilename in *; do [[ -f $genericFilename ]] || continue; ...; done`.

Comment: @chepner: gawk is being used to so that I can get to the main filename - separating/stripping the leading ./ and file extensions periods. Example: the find command gives me: ./myfilename.0.log. I only want myfilename.

Comment: If my answer to your question was too obvious and your question was really 'to what end' then I'll be happy to describe further. I'm not sure I've seen a for loop used in the way you have it shown so I'd be interested (and can open a separate question) in understanding if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *backquote* (`) is used in the old-style command substitution, The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is 
                easier to nest. See [BashFAQ82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082.)

Using backquotes, you'll have to escape required sequence for `gawk`:

```
category1Filenames=(`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "(\\\./)|(\\\.)" } ; { print $2 }' | sort -u`)
```

Aside: Feed `categoryFilenames` array in a loop instead:

```
while read -r line; do
    categoryFilenames+=("$line")
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "(\./)|(\.)" } ; { print $2 }' | sort -u)
```

Now it is safer to iterate over `categoryFilenames` like you did, but with double-quotes:

```
for genericFilename in "${category1Filenames[@]}"; do  
  printf "%s\n" "$genericFilename"  
done
```

**Don't forget to "Double quote"** every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you say that the while approach is safer because it is bypassing subshells caused by pipelines (taken from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)? I'm relatively new to messing around with stdin, Process Substitution, etc... so I'm just trying to understand exactly what I would be doing with your while loop.

Comment: You're welcome! No. I suggest you to read [Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays), as it explains it along with several examples. Please also notice @chepner's comment on your question. You might be doing something useless and maybe simply wrong.

Comment: Thanks again. Interesting read and from that link i was able to find that it's good to use read with -d '', find with -print0, and understand why you suggest using quotation marks around variables. Without using -d '' and -print0 it will not properly handle filenames with spaces in them. I don't expect any filenames in the group of files I'm focusing on. But it's nice to know and guard against it before hand. I had missed @chepner's comment and hope I answered his question as I'm always eager to learn and find more efficient/appropriate ways of solving a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `find`, just iterate over all the files in the current directory, and use the shell to process only regular files and extract the file name.

```
for name in *; do
    [[ -f $name ]] || continue
    name_only=${name%%.*}
    printf "%s\n" "$name_only"
done
```

Comment: thanks! very interesting.. i don't understand how it does what it does but that's what these forums and google are for :). do you feel that this method is any more efficient than the find (if so, why - is it because it doesn't leave the 'shell' whereas using find does)?